# Php-Codeigniter : How to exit from ajax Manually .?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

In my CI project, im using a webpage and it includes a `<div name="call-ajax">` in which it calls an ajax **display_table.php** on a button click via js.

The ajax content is a `<table>.....</table>` loaded from database table. i provided a delete(button) option for each row to delete the corresponding row from both Html table and mysql table. for this i called a javascript fn() at onClick of Delete button. the js fn() will remove the corresponding Html table row and then call the controller like this

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url("somecontroller/delete_comapny"); ?>/"+Code+"/"+CId;
```

so this will call controller and then model to delete corresponding row from mysql table. after deletion it back to the Controller delete_comapny().

The problem was here. here i want to load **somepage.php**

```
$this->load->view('somepage');
```

as a normal webpage. but i get the somepage.php displayed as ajax (all the content in somepage.php is displayed on the element `<div name="call-ajax">` that i spefied in 1st paragraph). this is becouse of these all operation begins from an ajax **display_table.php**. so after all operation it display sompeage.php as ajax in `<div name="call-ajax">`

how i get a solution for this.? i just need to load a normal webpage.

any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: use second parameter of view as $this->load->view('somepage',true); now you will get view html as string. use it for your purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by thinking more deeply. the problem solved with Ajax. I called an ajax function onClick delete button. also the corresponding parameters are passed to the Ajax.

From the ajax part it calls a controller like follows

```
type: "POST",
url : 'delete_company',
data: { com_code: comcod, com_lic:comid } ,
    success: function(data){
       $('#display-table').html(data); 
}
```

on controller, it directly forwarded to model. at model I receive this values by

```
$co_lic= $this->input->post('com_lic');
$co_code= $this->input->post('com_code');
```

after deletion,control back to controller. I put an echo "succees" and this echo will display to the

```
<div id="display-table"></div>
```

So no more page loading problems and reached at what I expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can put js code inside somepage.php and make a redirect with

```
window.location
```